# Any way to grab struct from DLL using dlsym (Dynamic Linking) without header file (.h)?

Tags: c++, unix, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlsym

I have been looking everywhere for this question, but I cannot seem to get the answer for this.
So, every example I have been to is simply how to grab function pointers from SO file, which I have done. However, let just say I have this compiled as my .SO file:

(these codes compiled into `libsampleso.so`):

sampleso.hpp:

```
#IFNDEF SAMPLESO_HPP__
#DEFINE SAMPLESO_HPP__
struct carDescriptor
{
    const char* model;
    int prod_year;
    int wheel_num;
    const char* license_plate;
    const char* colour;
} car;

carDescriptor fillCarID(void);
#ENDIF
```

sampleso.cpp:

```
#include "sampleso.hpp"

//Struct car fillup function
carDescriptor fillCarID(void)
{
    car.model = "Ford Fiesta";
    car.prod_year = 2014;
    car.wheel_num = 4;
    car.colour = "Midnight Blue";
    car.license_plate = "D 1234 ABC";

    return car;
}
```

now, compiled, I've got these out of `objdump -T libsampleso.so`: `car` (the struct) and `_Z9fillCarIDv` (the function).

if the return value of `_Z9fillCarIDv()` (aka `fillCarID()`) is normal datatype (e.g. `string` or `int`), it's easy with `dlsym`. However, for this I need to cast the struct first and then the function. I've tried creating an empty struct, and then cast `dlsym` to it:

```
struct carDesc * cars;
cars = reinterpret_cast<struct carDesc*>(dlsym(hHandler,"car"));
```

but seems to be impossible to use that as the datatype for the function:

```
carDesc(*__fn_fillCarIDv)(void);
__fn_fillCarIDv = reinterpret_cast<carDesc(*)(void)>(dlsym(hHandler,"_Z9fillCarIDv"));

cars = __fn_fillCarIDv(); //doesn't work, error: function returns incomplete type "carDesc" C/C++(862)
```

Anyone ever tried to grab a struct using `dlsym` **without .h file**?

Also, how do you deal with the elements from the struct grabbed by `dlsym`? I know that you don't have the proper elements listed without .h file, and obviously some pointer shifting is necessary, but can anyone give me an example of how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: According to my personal experience this is somewhat difficult. As far as I know, It's not possible for C++ to "read in" or "generate" a type at run time. If you'd like to do FFI invocations, types like `void*` might help.

Comment: What's more, using `extern "C"` would simplify the generated symbol name of your function (since not mangled), and you may get better ABI compatibility.

Comment: @testfailedin1.08s That's just sample SO I've whipped up just so I can test this method myself. That was made to reflect an even more complex, third-party SO (so no way I can add `extern "C"` or modify it in any way). 

I was looking into dynamically link something like libmariadb.so (for connecting to MySQL/MariaDB) but without having .h file being included so i can completely be safe from LGPL since the final program will be closed-source (unfortunately, but that's not for discussion here).

Comment: Not using the header file from a library doesn't free you from the obligations of LGPL. If you don't want to use the header provided by the library you'd have to write your own equivalent header

Comment: @AlanBirtles I know the fact that I still need to provide access to the source codes of the library, mention all LGPL 2.1 license used by the aformentioned library, etc (and no problem to me or my team). But my team is scared that writing `#include "mysql.h"` in our main.cpp makes it _derivative works_ and forced to open source the main.cpp too. But I'm not a lawyer, just a programmer, so I just trying my best from what I can do with it.

Comment: LGPL would be pretty pointless if you couldn't use header files, it'd be no different to GPL

Comment: @AlanBirtles so, can I say that putting `#include "mysql.h"` in my main.cpp doesn't make the main.cpp covered in LGPL copyleft scheme? I've been traversing the law.stackexchange.com for days, and only dynamic linking is mentioned, but no one mentioned `#include `.

Comment: With the usual IANAL caveat yes including a header is fine